# got nan in keras tuner but it works when I train it

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, keras-tuner

I trained my network several times and I already got some results. Then I found out about the Keras tuner and wanted to find the best hyperparameters with it. but the loss in tuner always becomes nan ( it won't get nan if you train it regularly). I'm using MobileNetv3Small as the backbone and wanted to find optimal layers numbers and units.
here is my model build:

```
def build_model(hp):
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(base)
# Tune the number of layers.
if hp.Boolean('globalMax'):
  model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPool2D())
model.add(layers.Flatten())
for i in range(hp.Int("num_layers", 1, 3)):
    model.add(
        layers.Dense(
            # Tune number of units separately.
            units=hp.Int(f"units_{i}", min_value=3, max_value=12, step=1),
        )
    )
if hp.Boolean("dropout"):
    model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=0.1))
model.add(layers.Dense(3))
model.compile(loss=mae, optimizer='sgd',metrics=[mae])
return model
```

and I'm using

```
 `tuner = kt.RandomSearch(
    hypermodel=build_model,
    objective="val_loss",
    executions_per_trial=2,
    overwrite=True
)`
```

and this is the output:
Best val_loss So Far: nan
Total elapsed time: 00h 02m 28s
INFO:tensorflow:Oracle triggered exit

what is the problem? I already checked any other optimizer ( however it works with .fit perfectly), tried removing dropout and even normalization

Comment: Have you tried to change all layers to have dtype float64 ? Try this if not: `tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')`

Comment: @parsa if u maintain only the Flatten layer ? (or only the GlobalMaxPool2D)

Comment: @salehsargolzaee I'm pretty sure it has nothing to float type but just in case, I've tried and it didn't work. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I used Boolean for globalmaxpool2d so it tests when it's only flatten layer.

Comment: @parsa u should test with Flatten and GlobalMaxPool2D both active

Comment: I tried with both active @MarcoCerliani as I mentioned before

Comment: Have you tried to supply an activation (e.g; relu, prelu, etc.) to the `Dense` layers being created in the layer loop? The linear activation may be causing some instability. Also, what is the architecture of the model when you just call the `fit` method (which you mentioned had stable results)?

Comment: @danielcahall the architect is a globallmax, flatten 2 dense layers. I also tried multiple activitaions earlier and didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the problem. It happened because `keras_tuner` is just trying to find some validation with a small batch and in my situation, it will be nan because the number is nearly infinite. after trying a bigger batch, and changing the loss function, it could get out of being Nan all the time and found some results.